# How to deserialize when json data in Kafka is not clear when using Flink

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I want to calculate the data in Kafka through Flink,but the problem is the JASON Data in Kafka could be mutative.

like this:

`{"data":{"template":25,"name":"name"}}`

or this:

```
{"data"{"type":"type1","props":"props","strem":"stream1"}
```

And I can't know in advance how much data is included in this JSON.So there is a probelm when using Flink:

```
streamExecutionEnvironment.addSource(new FlinkKafkaConsumer010<KafkaEvent>("flink", new KafkaEventSchema(),
            kafkaProps))
            .flatMap(new KafkaEventToRow()).returns(getReturnType());
```

So how to define the pojo type and mapFuncation when the Json data like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to define a more generic deserialization Schema like Map

**Define the Schema**

```
class CustomSchema implements DeserializationSchema {

    private ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    @Override
    public Map<String,Object> deserialize(byte[] bytes) throws IOException {
        Map<String,Object> t = null;
        t = mapper.readValue(bytes, Map.class);
        return t;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEndOfStream(Object o) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public TypeInformation<Map> getProducedType() {
        return TypeInformation.of(new TypeHint<Map>() {
        });
    }
}
```

Now use this as the Schema

```
streamExecutionEnvironment
.addSource(new FlinkKafkaConsumer010<KafkaEvent>("flink", new CustomSchema(),......
```

Now you get a generic Map which can inturn contain any datastructure

Comment: but it seems occur another exception, when I try to convert the 'DataStream<Map<String,Object>>' into a Table,in this code `tableEnvironment.registerDataStream("Product", mapDataStream,"userId,productId")` will throw an exception: ''`org.apache.flink.table.api.TableException: Only the first field can reference an atomic type`. and if i do not write fields,it will work if sql write like this “select * from product”，but in this way i cant select specific field i want.

Comment: You can directly marry two different types. You have to convert it. either by serialize and deserializing or by constructing it manually.

Comment: Do you mean two different types of DataStream and Table?